# NilCheck fix on safe navigation operator (&.)

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.3, reek, safe-navigation-operator

This simple method on a class just run the `status` method using the safe navigation operator.

```
def current_status
  account&.status
end
```

But reek report this warning:

```
MyClass#current_status performs a nil-check [https://github.com/troessner/reek/blob/master/docs/Nil-Check.md]
```

#### How can I properly write methods like this to avoid Nil Check?

I've also verified [this post](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/tell-dont-ask) from thoughtbot but it seem like "too much" for just a safe navigation operator.

Ruby 2.3.1

Comment: Like reek says, this `mask bigger problems in your source code like not using OOP and / or polymorphism when you should`. I think you need to show more code, at least relevant parts of class that is containing current_status method.

Answer (score 2):

The advice from "Example 4" in the linked [post](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/tell-dont-ask) is verbose but pretty good :

```
class MyClass
  def initialize(with_account = nil)
    @account = Account.new if with_account
  end

  def current_status
    account.status
  end

  def account
    @account || NilAccount.new
  end
end

class Account
  def status
    "Up!"
  end
end

class NilAccount
  def status
    "Down!"
  end
end

puts MyClass.new(:with_account).current_status
#=> "Up!"
puts MyClass.new.current_status
#=> "Down!"
```

If it's "too much" for you, `account&.status` might be just fine.

Whatever you do : you'll need to **test your code** as much as possible!

Answer (score 0):

well, `tell-dont-ask` looks pretty good, but [`Example 4`](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/tell-dont-ask) looks like an overkill to resolve this specific case.

@andredurao I think, we can use this workaround to pass checks, for some reason `reek` is fine with it:

```
def current_status
  return unless account

  account.status
end
```